# HTC webview issues .getting force close

Tags: android

this is my custom web view

```
public class MycustomWebView extends WebView {

    public static boolean sClicked = false;
    private boolean mOverrideCheckIsTextEditor = true;

    public View mCross;

//  public MycustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
//      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
//  }

    public MycustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, android.R.attr.webViewStyle);
    }


    public MycustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MycustomWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        sClicked = true;
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!hasFocus()) {
                try {
                    requestFocus();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "error no focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("Focus issue", e.getMessage());
//                  Logger.v("can't get focus " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        try {
            // crashes on some devices
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {

         if (mOverrideCheckIsTextEditor) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onCheckIsTextEditor();
            }

    }

    @Override
    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        super.loadUrl(url);
    }



    public void setOverrideOnCheckIsTextEditor(boolean b) {

        mOverrideCheckIsTextEditor = b;
    }

}
```

this is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myweb1);

//      myWebView=  new WebView(this, null, android.R.attr.webViewStyle, true);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebView.setFocusable(true);
        myWebView.isFocusableInTouchMode();
        myWebView.requestFocus();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://developer.samsung.com/resources.do");
        }
}
```

this is my XMl code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.example.testproj.MycustomWebView
        android:id="@+id/myweb1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layerType="software" />

       <!--  <com.example.testproj.LiveWebView
        android:id="@+id/myweb1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layerType="software" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

my problem is when i am running my application in HTC device it is getting force close where as in other device such as nexus it is working fine . any one please help me

this is error log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.WebView$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebView.java:9972)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please check your minimum version support in the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved this by myself .i have just commented this code

```
@Override
    onCheckIsTextEditor() {

         if (mOverrideCheckIsTextEditor) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onCheckIsTextEditor();
            }

    }
```

and for me it is working. hope it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Please check your minimum version support in the manifest xml. Give the minimum version properly to support your device

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this bug is caused by custom implementation of Webkit browser in HTC devices. Solution is not known.

Android issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9995