# Webview Crash - On version 4.4.x - On Samsung devices mostly

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

My app's crash reports suggests that 99% of the mobiles that run Android 4.4.x on Samsung mobiles, is crashing with the following exception...

```
84  
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
85  
at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.getOutputDirFromContext(ResourceExtractor.java:307)
86  
at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.<init>(ResourceExtractor.java:266)
87  
at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.ResourceExtractor.get(ResourceExtractor.java:232)
88  
at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.prepareToStartBrowserProcess(BrowserStartupController.java:266)
89  
at com.android.org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupController.startBrowserProcessesSync(BrowserStartupController.java:186)
90  
at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess$1.run(AwBrowserProcess.java:49)
91  
at com.android.org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThreadBlocking(ThreadUtils.java:64)
92  
at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.start(AwBrowserProcess.java:45)
93  
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startChromiumLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:185)
94  
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.ensureChromiumStartedLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:113)
95  
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startYourEngines(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:209)
96  
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:218)
97  
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:517)
98  
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:484)
99  
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:464)
100 
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:453)
```

I guess, this is the issue with WebView implementation on Samsung devices. But, since the rate of crash is unusually high, i wish to know, is there a way, i can make Samsung devices use, my custom defined WebView(if i can make one?), instead of the Samsung's implementation of WebView.

If someone has any understanding of how i can get over this crash, please help me out. It crashes on the line, that says, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)`, so i guess, exception handling using try/catch might not be a good solution for me.

Comment: Can you post your WebView code?  I have a Samsung S4 with 4.4.4 that I can test with.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the reason?

Comment: Nope :( Left it as it might be a very specific device issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issues is related to HTC webview issues like in here :
[HTC webview issues .getting force close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332650/htc-webview-issues-getting-force-close)

Maybe you need to make custom webview and use it as a webview.